# Making JQuery extension $.fn.extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a plugin that will display a little helper when called for. It's supposed to be initiated like this:

```
$(el).santasLittleHelper([options])
```

The plugin then have some "events" just like the jquery UI has and they should be triggered like this:

```
$(el).santasLittleHelper('evetnName', [options])
```

I have a prototype working but I have a few concerns about future problems with my structure. Flooding the memory or having other issues with variable and function scopes when I keep on working on it. Here is an outline:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.santasLittleHelper = function(p1, p2) {

    return this.each(function() {
        var o = {
            showSpeed: 50,
            hideSpeed: 50,
            duration: 5000,
            delay: 0
        }
        var el = $(this);
        function init() {
            console.log('init 1');
        }
        var events = {
            show: function(opt) {},
            hide: function(opt) {},
            pulse: function(opt) {}
        }
        if(p1 == undefined) {//This is obviously the init call
            init();
        }
        if(typeof(p1) == 'object') {
            //Correctly added parameters would then mean that p1 is options
            //and is the only parameter added so we store the options and init
            $.extend(o, p1);
            init();
        }
        if(typeof(p1) == 'string') {
            //This is a call to an "event".
            //call the "event" function and supply possible options as arg
            events[p1](p2);
        }            
 });
}

})(jQuery);
```

Options can be supplied for each event call but should in that case only be available in that events function scope. This is because I might want the helper to do something out of the mental box I created him in by supplying options in the init call.

Will this approach fill up the memory a little by each call to $(el).santasLittleHelper('event') because of the declared variables in the beginning of the code?

I think it looks clean and understandable, but can improvements be done?

Comment: Be careful with code like this: `var init = function init() { ... }`.  It's safer (due to weird browser bugs) to just use `function init() { ... }` instead, which is almost exactly the same anyway.

Comment: True. I have edited the post. The function is still in the plugin scope only if I'm right?

Comment: Yes, it has almost exactly the same effect as declaring it with `var`; in fact I'd say that if it causes a problem, that probably means something else is wrong :-)  In your case it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to practices described [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth), it seems to me that you're doing it right, but I would try if possible to make o and events independent of each (declare it before and pass as optional parameter if override is needed else use unique declared outside of each?)

Comment: Good point! I'll consider it. Am I understanding you correct if calling the event instead looked like this: events[p1](o, p2) and the function signature was function(defOptions, tempOptions)?

Comment: yes, and inside you check if tempOptions == null, then you replace tempOptions with "defaults", and defaults is used by reference so you don't flood memory